# Bind event on FancyBox iFrame element

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to bind an event on an element that is ajax loaded in an iFrame loaded in a fancyBox.

Heres is my code that is on the page that loads the Box. Not in the iFrame :

```
    $('a.box').fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
            },
            locked: false
        }
    },
    padding : 0,
    width: 868,
    fitToView: true,
    iframe: {
        preload   : true
    },
    beforeShow: function(){
        $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('.admin-content').css('width', '100%');
        console.info('Content Showing');
        alert('content SHowing');
    },
    afterLoad: function(){
        alert('content loaded');
        $('.fancybox-iframe').ready(function(){
            console.info('Content loaded');
            console.info($('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('a.read-only'));
            $('.fancybox-iframe body').find('a.read-only').bind('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var link = $(this);
                var media_type = link.data('media_type');
                parent.$.fancybox.close();

                var $mce = parent.tinymce.get('<?php echo $mceclass; ?>');
                var content = '';
                if (media_type == 'image'){
                    var img = link.find('img');
                    var img_src = img.attr('src');
                    var img_alt = img.attr('alt');
                    var imgzoom_src = img.attr('src').replace('_thumb', '_zoom');
                    content = '<a href="'+imgzoom_src+'" class="fancy" title="'+img_alt+'"><img src="'+img_src+'" width="'+SUBO_IMG_THUMB_WIDTH+'" alt="'+img_alt+'"/></a>';
                }else if(media_type == 'video' || media_type == 'audio'){

                }else{

                }
                $mce.focus();
                $mce.insertContent(content);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Pleae note that there are many tests I've done and I noticed that the console.log don't show in Firebug...

**I'm using fancybox 2 and the page and the iframe are on the same domain.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Pierre M.

Comment: Try using `$('.fancybox-iframe').load()` instead of  `$('.fancybox-iframe').ready()`

Comment: Hi JFK, thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. Another thing is the callbacks beforeShow et afterLoad doesn't fire either... :/

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the `afterShow` callback to `bind` your events inside the iframe and target the proper selectors (you always need to use the `.contents()` method to find the *selectors* inside the iframe) so try :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("a.box").fancybox({
        // API options
        type: "iframe", // you need this
        afterShow: function () {
            $(".fancybox-iframe").ready(function () {
                $(".fancybox-iframe")
                    .contents()
                    .find(".close") // find your selector
                    .on("click", function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        // do something here after click
                }); // on click
            }); // iframe ready
        } // afterShow
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

**NOTE**: iframe and ajax interactions are subject to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: All scripts are "Same origin". The problem is that my fancybox did not fire any events "after" or "before"... :/ As I had to get my project going on, I decided to switch to ColorBox plugin and it's working well... Maybe, I'll give another try to fancybox and iFrame on another project. Thanks anyway. Pierre M.

Comment: After a long research, I found this answer and this is the correct method.